# Scala: Josephus problem with Actors

Tags: scala, actor

Another stab at the [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), this time using Actors. `N` people stand in a circle and every `step`th person is eliminated until one is remaining.

The way I solve it here is to give each actor a reference to their successor, and the actors send their successor a count of places since the last elimination. If an actor is eliminated, it replies with a reference to its successor so that the previous actor now links the one after.

I've hardly used Actors before. I'd like general comments, but in particular I'm wondering:

- is using Actors appropriate for this problem?
- are the messages I used sensible?
- is the wait for reply necessary?
- how would you do it differently?

btw I'm going to try this with Akka as well - if that will make any major difference to the solution that you know of, please mention!

```
object Josephus_Actors extends App {
  import actors._

  val N = 40
  val step = 3

  case class Person(id: Int) extends Actor { Self =>
    // would like to make `next` private[this], but it's then very tricky to set up
    var next: Person = _
    private[this] var alive = true
    def act {
      while (alive) {
        // Messages consist of (count, sender) where count is distance from last man out
        receive {
          // last man standing
          case (_, Self) => {
            println("Winner: "+id)
            sys.exit(0)
          }          
          // kill self
          case (x: Int, _) if x == step => {
            alive = false
            reply {next}
          }
          // kill next 
          case (x: Int, _) if x == step - 1 => {
            // wait until we have received our next value
            next !? ((step, Self)) match {
              case a: Person => next = a
              case _ =>                
            }
            next ! (1, Self)
          }
          /* pass on message */
          case (x: Int, _) => {
            next ! (x + 1, Self)
          }
          case other => println(id + " unrecognized message: " + other)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  val acts = 1 to N map Person
  acts foreach { p =>
    // add reference to successor
    p.next = p.id match { 
      case N => acts(0)
      case x => acts(x)
    }
    p.start()
  }
  acts(0) ! (1, null)  
}
```

Comment: It's a fun way to model the problem, sure. But it's probably more efficient to simply use a linked list for a naive implementation. Your wikipedia pages shows that the best solution uses dynamic programming and executes in O(n) time. So it's probably not appropriate, but a nice way to learn about actors.

Comment: @Cygal this should be O(n) too and acts very much like a linked list. Actors are quite lightweight although prob not so much as a collection node. To me sending messages seems like just an un-typesafe form of method invocation but it may just be that I don't understand them properly yet

Comment: I think their "point" is that they run concurrently in separate threads although that's of little use in this problem

Answer (score 2):

> would like to make `next` private[this], but it's then very tricky to set up

To achieve that, you can define the initial next person as a `lazy val` field, and then define a `var` locally in the `act` method:

```
case class Person(id: Int) extends Actor { Self =>
  private[this] lazy val initialNext: Person = acts((id + 1) % N)
  ...
  def act {
    var next = initialNext
```

The initialization then simplifies to

```
val acts = 1 to N map Person
acts foreach { _.start }
acts(0) ! (1, null)
```

Answer (score 2):

You use in your solution a synchronous call (`!?`) which prevents the actor from doing something else while waiting (in this example, this is not a problem). You could easily implement a *true* asynchronous solution by reacting on persons sent back in case that a person killed itself. The `act` method then looks as follows:

```
def act {
  var next = initialNext
  while (alive) {
    receive {
      // last man standing
      case (_, Self) => println("Winner: "+id); sys.exit(0)

      // kill self
      case (`step`, _) => alive = false; reply {next}

      // receive killed 
      case p: Person => next = p; next ! (1, Self)

      // pass on message
      case (x: Int, _) => next ! (x + 1, Self)

      case other => println(id + " unrecognized message: " + other)
    }
  }
}
```